# Output a Menu with just needed classes for ul and li,. Nothing more

Tags: routes, theming, navigation

Normally a drupal menu is being rendered like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li class="first leaf"><a title="" href="xxx">xxx</a></li>
<li><a class="active-trail active" title="" href="yyy">yyy</a></li>
<li class="last leaf"><a title="" href="zzz">zzz</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want it to be rendered as for a particular menu:

```
<ul class="side-menu">
<li><a href="xxx">xxx</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="yyy">yyy</a></li>
<li><a href="zzz">zzz</a></li>
</ul>
```

So I have the following in my template.php

```
function mymod_menu_tree__menu_about_us($variables) {
  return '<ul class="side-menu">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}

function mymod_menu_link__menu_about_us(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';
  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }
  $class = "";
  $classes_of_this_li = $element['#attributes']['class'];
  if (in_array($classes_of_this_li, 'active-trail')) {
    $class = 'active';
  }
  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href']);
  return '<li class="' . $class . '">' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

The ul is rendered as i want it to be. But the active class for the li is never there. Something must be wrong with below part

```
if (in_array($classes_of_this_li, 'active-trail')) {
    $class = 'active';
  }
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you checked whats in the $classes_of_this_li array?

Answer (score 1):

Try switching the parameters to `in_array`. `in_array` takes the `needle` first and the `haystack` (array) second.

*Edit: unless that was a typo...*

**Edit**

[PHP Docs for `in_array()`.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

> ```
> bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )
> ```
>
> Searches haystack for needle using loose comparison unless strict is
>   set.